# Z-index item not clickable on mobile

Tags: html, css, maps, mobile-safari, z-index

I'm trying to overlay a text input field on a map. However, while the input box is clickable on desktop, it has not proved clickable on mobile browsers. Below is the relevant HTML code. Note that div `map` is wrapped in another div with `id="middle"`.

```
<div id="map">
    <input id="locField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" style="position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right; margin: 12px;"></input>
</div>
```

So the input field (`locField`) has z-index 10, and the `map` div has z-index 9, as shown in the CSS:

```
div#middle {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#map {position: relative; z-index: 9;}
```

The `-webkit-transform` and `position: relative`s are vestigials of my attempts to fix this issue. They may or may not be helpful but I've left them in for now. How can I make the input field clickable on mobile?

Comment: It may be helpful to see the code in greater context, to ensure there aren't other `z-index` issues.  That being said, `</input>` isn't a thing (inputs are self-closing), and the `<input>` would natively inherit the `z-index` of `#map` so you may be able to eliminate that bit of inline styling.

Comment: I fixed the problem by taking the `<input>` field out of the `<div id="map">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this, Nicholas?

```css
div#middle {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  background-color: #999;
}
#map {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#locField {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle">
  <div id="map">
    <iframe width="100%"
height="100%"
src="https://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&#038;q=London&#038;ie=UTF8&#038;t=&#038;z=14&#038;iwloc=A&#038;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    
      <input id="locField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" style="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```